# reading any pc compatible racing wheel input

Tags: python, c++, c, windows

I am an Electrical Engineer student and I am currently doing a Final Year Project on setting up a simulation platform for driving to test my drowsiness detecting device. I am currently looking for methods that can retrieve racing wheel's input data such as steering wheel angle because I need those data to operate my device effectively. I have tried to look up on the internet and I only found these documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.racingwheelreading
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/racing-wheel-and-force-feedback

It seems like windows only support device that is compatible with xbox one or xbox 360 steering wheel. Due to our limiting allowed budget, we could only find some cheap steering wheels that are compatible with PS4/PS3 and PC. Is there any other way that can read input data like steering angle from any pc compatible racing wheel? By the way, I am using windows operating system.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: You probably need to look at the documentation for the wheel that you are using. Maybe the wheels follow some standard, for which there will be documentation for.

Comment: [tag:Python], [tag:C], and [tag:C++] do not go together.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, if your steering wheels are marked as PC compatible, they appear in Windows as joysticks.  These devices can be read using the Multimedia Joystick API or DirectInput.

The Multimedia Joystick API docs are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757116(v=vs.85).aspx.  You use this API by calling a series of C functions, like `joyGetPosEx()`, which are all available in Windows.h.

DirectInput is more complicated to set up, and works using COM.  DirectInput docs are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416842(v=vs.85).aspx

XInput is supposed to be the next generation API for input devices, but it only supports input devices that have the layout (joysticks, buttons, etc.) of an Xbox 360 controller.

The documents that you found work with Microsoft's newer "Universal Windows Platform," which is used in the Microsoft store.  UWP apps are not able to use DirectInput, and are probably not able to use the old joystick API either.

Comment: Thank you, Jack C. That was very helpful